# Using env values in Vite in Laravel: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-10

I have a CDN setup for serving from an `ASSET_URL` in my Laravel config.

So that Vite knows where to serve images from in CSS files, I appended an `@` symbol in the CSS like this:

```
.element {
    background-color: #f7f8fb;
    background-image: url('@/images/background.png');
}
```

My `vite.config.js` looks like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import {defineConfig} from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import {resolve} from 'path'
import {homedir} from 'os'

export default defineConfig({
    server: detectServerConfig(import.meta.env.VITE_APP_DOMAIN || 'localhost'),
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': import.meta.env.VITE_ASSET_URL || path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

function detectServerConfig(host) {
    let keyPath = resolve(homedir(), `.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.key`)
    let certificatePath = resolve(homedir(), `.config/valet/Certificates/${host}.crt`)

    if (!fs.existsSync(keyPath)) {
        return {}
    }

    if (!fs.existsSync(certificatePath)) {
        return {}
    }

    return {
        hmr: {host},
        host,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certificatePath),
        },
    }
}
```

This will cause this error to be thrown when I do `npm run build`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_APP_DOMAIN')
```

I followed the [Laravel 10 directions in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#environment-variables) for this so in my `.env` I have defined each var's Vite equivalent:

```
VITE_APP_DOMAIN="${APP_DOMAIN}"
VITE_ASSET_URL="${ASSET_URL}"
```

What is wrong with the setup here?